# How to handle PCB design rule check when using a potentiometer with only two pins as a rheostat?

Tags: potentiometer, kicad, rheostat

As a part of a simple PCB, I want to use a potentiometer as a rheostat which will vary the feedback resistance of a Schmitt-trigger as follows:

[image]

I use KiCad and if I leave pin 3 open as shown above, I get error in electrical rules check as expected. I want to completely omit pin 3 and use a classical potentiometer as a variable resistor. The pot I want to mount on the PCB look like this and I wan to use its two pins to vary the feedback resistance:

[image]

**Edit:**

Result of connecting pin 2 and 3:

[image]

Comment: You can add a  NoERC/NoDRC directive. It tells the rule checker to ignore this error.

Comment: The ERC error is really just a warning to the user - it does not prevent you from doing the PCB layout.  You can place a "No ERC" marker on the unused pin to suppress the error message.  I try to clear all ERC (and DRC) errors, but sometimes that's difficult.  If you know that what you have done is what you wawnt, but can't easily clear the error, you can ignore the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect pins 2 and 3 then if the wiper—even momentarily—loses contact with the track, it will default to the resistance of the whole track instead of being open-circuit.

The design rules will be happy that all the pins are connected.

Comment: But wouldn't connecting pins 2 and 3 make "1 to 2" and "2 to 3" portions of the pot resistor in parallel?

Comment: @user16307 No, in normal operation it shorts out the track from the wiper to terminal 3, which isn't part of the circuit.

Comment: Please see my edit. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @user16307 Exactly, it's standard practice to use such a connection.